# Run Android Apps on Ubuntu

Tags: android

How can you run android apps on ubuntu?

I have seen that there is some way to run ubuntu on the phone, but I want it the other way.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/install-android-apps-ubuntu-archon

Answer (score 0):

look for some [android emulators](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechapple.net%2F2014%2F05%2F5-best-android-emulators-linux-run-android-apps-linux-ubuntulinuxmintfedoraarchlinuxopensusemageiacentos-etc%2F&ei=kfeuVMqOMJPiggS004KIDg&usg=AFQjCNH-FwuiYPm6vMNh-gPsdBJoyj4aig&sig2=4DKa222znxgjmp3bMUME6A&bvm=bv.83339334,d.eXY)

Answer (score 0):

1. Hang with QEMU emulation provided by [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/), this is the most original and most naive way to do Android emulation ob Linux.
2. Play with [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/), but you would need VirtualBox.